# BASH grep result as array name

Tags: arrays, string, bash, macos, grep

Heyhey,
since this is my first post please be patient :) I try my best.

I try to "grep" the language out of my system (osx) and take this as a string name to set a language.

I've got some strings called `$en['a' 'b' 'c']`, `$de['d' 'e' 'f']` and `$fr['g' 'h' 'i']` somewhere...

I use:

```
language=$(locale | grep LANG= | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d_ -f1)
```

which gives me a ISO value like en, fr, de, ...

Here comes my main problem. I just can't just use `${language[*]}`.
It feels like I tried everything. Already doing try an error with `{}` `()` `''` and `$`.

Only thing I found out while debugging is `language` results in

`language=ISO` (so this works correct)

and if I try to get this value as my desired string

```
echo ${language[*]} , ${language[0]} , ${language[1]}
```

results in

```
 ISO , ISO ,
```

which is not correct. It seems like I'm creating a new string but I want to use the existing ones.
Don't know any more keywords to google :(

Comment: What exactly is the input? What output do you expect?

Comment: I just filled in some input right now. I expect that the output of ${en[@]} and ${language[@]} are the same.

Answer (score 0):

These all use array syntax:

```
echo ${language[*]} , ${language[0]} , ${language[1]}
```

But the way you created the variable, this is not an array, this is a simple variable:

```
language=$(locale | grep LANG= | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d_ -f1)
```

To access its value, use simply `$language`, for example:

```
echo $language
```

Also, the pipeline with `locale`, `grep` and `cut` gets the first two characters of the `LANG` variable in a very inefficient way.
You can get it more efficiently using a substring:

```
language=${LANG:0:2}
```

If you want to use an array (though I don't see the point here), then you must put parentheses around the values to assign, for example:

```
language=(${LANG:0:2})
```

This array in this example has one element, you can access its value like this:

```
echo ${language[0]}
```

Note that the syntax of Bash is very strict with respect to symbols and spaces, every little detail may make a big difference, so it's important to write accurately.

You can paste your scripts to shellcheck.net to check for trivial errors.

You can read more about arrays in `man bash`.

Comment: Shouldnt I use array syntax, if I got strings in arrays?  You're right thats realy more efficient, thanks. Still can't access my array through $language[ ]

Comment: it's going to be either an array or a string (you understand that, right?). If you really want an array, do `language=( $(local ..... | ....) )` . Good luck.